# Trying to implement bidirectional self-referential association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

(I'm translating the code as I write, so I apologize for any mistakes!)

I'm trying to implement a bidirectional self referential relation involving the `Associates` table and a join table `Property`. I tried following [this post](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association) but something is still wrong.

The way it's supposed to work is, an `associate` can be the proprietor of zero or more `associates`, and consequently an `associate` may have zero or more `proprietors` (makes more sense in the context of the application).

So I created the `Property` model:

```
class CreateProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :properties do |t|
      t.integer :proprietor_id
      t.integer :property_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

So the table contains only the ids of one `proprietor` and one `property`, both `associate`s, per entry.

Following the tutorial linked above, I came to this configuration:

`Associate.rb`:

```
...
has_many :properties 
has_many :related_properties, :through => :properties
has_many :proprietors, :class_name => "Property", :foreign_key => "proprietor_id"
has_many :related_proprietors :through => :proprietors, :source => :associate
...
```

`Property.rb`:

```
belongs_to :associate
belongs_to :related_properties, :class_name => "Associate"
```

However when I try to use these relations (`<% @associate.related_properties.each do |property| %>`), I get this error:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column properties.related_properties_id does not exist
LINE 1: ... INNER JOIN "propriedades" ON "associados"."id" = "proprieda...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "associates".* FROM "associates" INNER JOIN "properties" ON "associates"."id" = "properties"."related_properties_id" WHERE "properties"."associate_id" = $1
```

Basically, the column names are wrong in the generated SQL: `properties.related_properties_id` should be `properties.proprietor_id`, and `properties.associate_id` should be `properties.proprietor_id` as well.

What have I done wrong, and how can I fix this code to get the correct relations?

Comment: Are the names of the models translated from another language because an associate being the proprietor of (owning) another associate does not make much sense. Or are you trying to create a self referential relationship where one employee can be for example the manager of another employee?

Comment: It's translated from another language. In this case, an `associate` can be an actual person or a company, and an associate of the type `person` can be the proprietor of an associate of the type `company`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup two seperate associations since the foreign key on Property depends on what the Associates role is.

```
class Associate
  # defines relations where Associate is the "owning" party
  has_many :properties_as_proprietor, 
    class_name: 'Property',
    foreign_key: 'proprietor_id'
  has_many :properties, 
    through: :properties_as_property,
    source: :property # what to select on Property

  # defines relations where Associate is the "owned" party
  has_many :properties_as_property, 
    class_name: 'Property',
    foreign_key: 'property_id'
  has_many :proprietors, 
    through: :properties_as_proprietor,
    source: :proprietor # what to select on Property
end

class Property
  belongs_to :proprietor, class_name: 'Associate'
  belongs_to :property, class_name: 'Associate'
end
```

Comment: The reason it works in the rails tutorial case is that one of the associations on `Friend` is named `:user` which can be automatically deduced to the correct model and table. If you had named the association `:associate` it would have worked the same way.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just a note, after `class_name: 'Property'`, both times, a comma is missing. Other than that, it's perfect. Also, thanks for explaining why the tutorial didn't work in this case